# SQL issue with my code. Database not parsing into app

Tags: python, milestone

I'm doing a project for the complete Python course on Stackskills, and I have a problem running an app that should add a book name and author to a database. when I try to add a book, this is what happens:

```
Your choice: a
What is the name of the book you want to add? clean code
Who is the author of the book? jose
Unknown command, please try again.
```

it seems like the app.py just forgets it is running prompt_add_book() and starts from the beginning when it asks for a book. I'm not sure what is going wrong here. any help would be appreciated.

```
def prompt_add_book():
    name = input("What is the name of the book you want to add? ")
    author = input("Who is the author of the book? ")
    database.insert_book(name, author)
```

```
def insert_book(name:str, author : str):
    with DatabaseConnection('data.db') as connection:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO books(name,author) VALUES (?, ?)', (name,author))
```

I was expecting for the book to be added to the database. It was working before, when I wasn't using sqlite3 and just putting the books into a file, but for some reason it is not working when SQL is involved.

Comment: Looks like you forgot `connection.commit()`.

Comment: I don't see `Unknown command` anywhere in the code you posted. That's coming from something else.